# Recommended node inspector version for node v0.10.38

Tags: node.js

I have node inspector setup to connect with my node app.

it works to an extent. In the beginning it stops due to the debug-break setting and it stops at the breakpoints I put in my config file. However once I get it going and make a request, it does not stop at any of the break points in the request handling code.

I suspect its because I have Node Inspector v0.12.8 which is not well compatible with node v0.10.38.

Anyone know what the recommended version is?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of staying on v0.10 (which there will be no more releases for since the end of October 2016), you're better off using at least the latest LTS branch (v6.x as of this writing) which supports Chrome Dev Tools out of the box with the `--inspect` command line option.